# Trying to query with filter Status Notion API Database

Tags: javascript, api, notion-api

```
import { Client } from "@notionhq/client";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const notion = new Client({ auth: process.env.NOTION_API_KEY });
  const database = await notion.databases.query({
    database_id: process.env.NOTION_DB_KEY,
    filter: {
      status: "Completed",
     
    },
  });
 
  res.send(database);
}
```

I am trying to filter by status but i couldnt understand how to filter by status

Answer (score 0):

The status filter expect a `StatusPropertyFilter` object, so you should define the filter as following.

```
filter: {
  status: {
    equals: "Completed"
  },
},
```

And beyond `equals` you can also filtering by `does_not_equal`, `is_empty`, `is_not_empty` .

So the whole code will looks like this

```
import { Client } from "@notionhq/client";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const notion = new Client({ auth: process.env.NOTION_API_KEY });
  const database = await notion.databases.query({
    database_id: process.env.NOTION_DB_KEY,
    filter: {
      status: {
        equals: "Completed"
      },
    },
  });
 
  res.send(database);
}
```

You can also check the notion-sdk-js source code in Github for more information

https://github.com/makenotion/notion-sdk-js/blob/main/src/api-endpoints.ts#L9251